# Why live AppEngine is not calling my servlet filter?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, servlet-filters

I have a servlet filter written for my app engine project.

It is being called from the local development machine.

But it is not called when I put the code in Google App Engine live server.

Can anybody explain why?

This is how it is mapped in web.xml

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>ErrorHandlerFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.fms.advocacy.filters.ErrorHandlerFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ErrorHandlerFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

And this is the filter.

```
public class ErrorHandlerFilter implements Filter {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ErrorHandlerFilter.class.getName());

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException { 
            log.warning("Entered ErrorHandlerFilter!!"); 
    }
}
```

PS: I am using Google Cloud Endpoint for coding my APIs

Comment: How is your servlet filter mapped?

Comment: Yes. I configured web.xml. It is working in my local development server, but not in the live AppEngine Server.

Comment: I asked for **how**, not if it is in web.xml.

Comment: sorry. I will update it in question.

Comment: Updated the web.xml part in question

Comment: So, what if you redirect your app to, example `/_ah/api/test` on your browser, what does it do?

Comment: Then I am getting it. I understood the problem. I am positing it as answer.

Comment: There you go! Glad you figured it out...

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the `<url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>`.
In server the url is changed to `<url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>`

Now it is working.